# How can I calculate weighted values based on available funds and number of items in a set?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to work up something that I feel like should be fairly simple, but I'm running into a solid wall. I'm putting together some basic budgeting functionality. For my "wish list", I would like a dollar amount assigned to an item based on the following criteria:

- The number of items in the set
- The amount of money available
- The priority of the item

In order for this to be successful, the following conditions should be met:

- The dollar value assigned should automatically update based on the number of items in the set.
- The dollar value assigned should automatically update based on funds available.
- The "Budged Amount" column (below) should always equal the available funds.

Here is a sample data set:

**Available Funds: $500**

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| PRIORITY | ITEM NAME | Budgeted Amount  |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 1        | Thing 1   | 92.86            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 2        | Thing 2   | 85.71            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 3        | Thing 3   | 78.57            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 4        | Thing 4   | 71.43            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 5        | Thing 5   | 64.29            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 6        | Thing 6   | 57.14            |
|-----------------------------------------|
| 7        | Thing 7   | 50               |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

So basically, if the number of "things" changes, the "Budgeted Amount" should update to correctly add up to the "Available Balance". Likewise, if the "Available Funds" value changes, the "Available Balance" column should update appropriately.

Ideally, this should be weighted based on "Ranking". Otherwise, I'd just use the calculated average across the board and it takes away the point of having things listed as "more important".

I've tried some fairly convoluted (and frankly) ridiculous calculations. I've also tried things as simple as 71.43*1.3 for the top spot. All of this works fine as long as there are seven items in the list.

**Disclaimers**

- The decimal values above are rounded, so they probably don't add up to the "Available Funds" exactly.
- I'm actually implementing this in PHP, but I'm prototyping in Excel. A PHP solution would work as well.

Any assistance or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I don't even know how to title this question.

Comment: Please avoid the wish list and provide the relevant code segment along with specific problems you're facing with the code you have so far.

Comment: The "wish list" illustrates the results that I'm attempting to achieve. I'm not sure why I would avoid sharing it. There's also no code segment, as the prototyping is being done in Excel. I'm really looking for help with the math. (Example given in the question.) The PHP tag was added at the suggestion of SO. I guess I can probably remove that.

Comment: it's an interesting math problem I think. once you devise an appropriate formula, the implementation should be easy.

Comment: If this is purely about the math, I'm not sure it belongs on SO, which is about coding questions.

Comment: @devlin That's probably valid. I clicked "Ask Question", tagged it and here it sits. Guess I was probably on SO when I hit the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about the ratio of the reverse rank to the total running sum of ranks. This value will give the rank item's budget coefficient.

```
<?php

$available_budget = 500;
echo "<h1>Total Budget = $available_budget</h1>";

$items = array(
  0 => "thing 1",
  1 => "thing 2",
  2 => "thing 3",
  3 => "thing 4",
  4 => "thing 5",
  5 => "thing 6",
  6 => "thing 7"
);

$count = count($items);

// first pass calculate total running sum
$total_running_sum = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++){
  $total_running_sum += $i;
}

// table header
echo "<table border=1><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>budget</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

// start with the last item (lowest rank)
$items = array_reverse($items);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){

  echo "<tr><td>$items[$i]</td>".
  // divide the reverse rank by total running sum and multiply by available budget
  "<td>". (($i+1)/$total_running_sum)*$available_budget ."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</tbody></table>";

?>
```

This will produce the following table:

```
Total Budget = 500

Item    budget

thing 7 17.857142857143

thing 6 35.714285714286

thing 5 53.571428571429

thing 4 71.428571428571

thing 3 89.285714285714

thing 2 107.14285714286

thing 1 125
```

The budget column will always sum to exactly the total budget.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I was secretly hoping to try to avoid the "running total" method and find some super heavy mathematical formula that relied on the number of items in the array. But this is great, also. I need to modify it slightly, but it should work just fine. Thanks again!